# Silverlight 4 Calendar Binding to SelectedDate not updating

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, silverlight-4.0

Morning folks,

I'm using Silverlight 4 and using the Calendar object's SelectedDate to try to populate the Text element of a Textblock, but changing the selection of the calendar isn't updating the binding:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="currentWeekLabel" Text="{Binding SelectedDate, ElementName=ByWeekCalendar, Converter={StaticResource WeekChosenConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="White" Padding="10 0 0 0" FontWeight="Black" />
```

I get no binding errors but do I need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on the SelectedDate property or something, I can't understand why the Converter is never being entered.

Thanks,
Becky

Comment: "Morning", when and where is it morning?

Answer (score 0):

You won't need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` because you aren't binding to a property defined in your code.  The `SelectedDate` property of the Calendar control is a `DependencyProperty` so it should update fine.

Try removing the converter from the binding, if it starts working your problem is in your converter.  If not then show us the Xaml for the Calendar.